# open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) api23?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-file, runtime-permissions

I know about the runtime permissions and I've taken that into consideration but it still doesn't work. I have added these lines to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

this is my **onCreate** method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
    if (shouldAskPermissions()) {
        askPermissions();
    }
    generateNoteOnSD(this,fileName,msg);
    readFile(fileName);
}
```

this is for **asking and granting permission**

```
protected static boolean shouldAskPermissions() {
    return (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1);
}

@TargetApi(23)
protected void askPermissions() {
    String[] permissions = {
            "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
            "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    };
  /*  int requestCode = 200;
    requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);*/
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, permissions, 1);
    }
}
```

and these are the **writing and reading methods**

```
 public static void generateNoteOnSD(Context context, String sFileName, String sBody) {
        try {
            File root = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
            Log.e("file path is ", String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
            String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
            writer.append(separator); // this will add new line ;

            //FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
            writer.append(sBody);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void readFile(String file1){
        //Find the directory for the SD Card using the API
//*Don't* hardcode "/sdcard"
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
        File file = new File(sdcard,file1);

//Read text from file
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            //You'll need to add proper error handling here
        }

//Find the view by its id
        Log.e("text",text.toString());
    }
```

**EDIT**
This is my stacktrace:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/CrowdSensingData: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:487)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:58)
W/System.err:     at enis.example.com.alarmmanagertest.FileAndServerHandlingActivity.generateNoteOnSD(FileAndServerHandlingActivity.java:128)
W/System.err:     at enis.example.com.alarmmanagertest.ActivityRecognitionService.handleDetectedActivities(ActivityRecognitionService.java:107)
W/System.err:     at enis.example.com.alarmmanagertest.ActivityRecognitionService.onStart(ActivityRecognitionService.java:122)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:459)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3209)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1586)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:473)
```

Comment: `requestPermissions()` is asynchronous. When it returns, the user has not even been *asked* for permission yet, let alone granted it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see your point, but I do not understand how to change the code. I'm a beginner with android

Comment: This stuff is covered in any up-to-date book or course on Android app development, and to a lesser extent in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). In [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Files/FilesEditor), I use [an `AbstractPermissionActivity`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Files/FilesEditor/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/fileseditor/AbstractPermissionActivity.java) that isolates the code needed to ask for runtime permissions when the activity is started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the permissions are not granted yet you should not call methods which need them immediately. Call them in onRequestPermissionsResult instead. This guarantees that they only get executed as soon as the permissions are granted by the user.

```
if (shouldAskPermissions()) {
    askPermissions();
} else {
    generateNoteOnSD(this,fileName,msg);
    readFile(fileName);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                generateNoteOnSD(this,fileName,msg);
                readFile(fileName);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Furthermore, include [ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) in your shouldAskPermissions() method.

**Edit 2:**
Here's an implementation for shouldAskPermissions()

```
protected boolean shouldAskPermissions() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        return false;
    }
    int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    return  (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't solve the issue, I'm still getting W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: @futureengineer please post the full stacktrace and your new shouldAskPermissions() method

Comment: Just to make sure of something before posting the stacktrace so you don't waste your time. How am I supposed to change the method shouldAskPermissions() ? it just verifies the version in order to check if it needs runtime permissions. And if you mean the method askPermissions(), am I supposed to change it ? it just requests permissions which triggers the method  onRequestPermissionsResult that you have posted in your reply, am I misunderstanding something ?

Comment: it still gives the same error even after trying the code in you edited post, I'll add the stacktrace to my original post

Comment: @futureengineer I have copied the code and it worked just fine. Make sure that you made all the changes properly.

Comment: okay thank you for your help. It works now, although I have no idea what was wrong before. I just created a new project and did everything from the start and it works just fine now.